# Treeview does not contain a definition for 'DrawMode'

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, .net-1.1

In .Net Framework 1.1 , Treeview does not contain a definition for 'DrawMode' property . I need to UI customize all TreeNodes.

Comment: my requirement is should be  .Net framework 1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.treeview1.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint,true);
```